# Tips for FHIR API in .NET

Tags: .net, api, hl7-fhir, hateoas

I'm tasked with writing a FHIR API in .NET.

For an API/server to be FHIR compatible does it have to implement the HATEOAS/links part - for example, does an `Encounter` object have to have a *link* to its `Patient` object, or can it have the entire `Patient` object in the `Encounter`'s `subject` field?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a little complicated. The Encounter.patient is a reference, and so you can't include the entire patient object in the subject field - it just contains a URL that references it (or sometimes, just an identifier if the URL can't be determined).

But there is a special case, which is that the patient object can be put in Encounter.contained, and then the reference from Encounter.subject is a relative reference (e.g. something like reference="#pat")

Comment: great! thanks, that helps! am I correct in assuming that a FHIR server would also adhere to the HATEOAS principle?

Comment: well... partly that depends on quite what you mean. If you mean just what you asked about then, yes, it should adhere. But not all servers that claim to conform actually do

Answer (score 0):

Unless your task is a study exercise, please know that there is already a widely used, open-source .NET FHIR API out there: https://github.com/FirelyTeam/fhir-net-api/